# Why does using a regex and .scan produce these results?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

```
>> "aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/(.)/)
=> [["a"], ["a"], ["a"], ["a"], ["a"], ["a"], ["f"], ["b"], ["f"], ["b"], ["f"], ["s"], ["j"], ["j"], ["s"], ["e"], ["e"], ["w"]]


>> "aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.))/)
=> [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["s", "s"], ["j", "j"], ["j", "j"], ["s", "s"], ["e", "e"], ["e", "e"], ["w", "w"]]

>> "aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.)\2*)/)
=> [["aaaaaa", "a"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["s", "s"], ["jj", "j"], ["s", "s"], ["ee", "e"], ["w", "w"]]


>> "aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.)\1*)/)
=> [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["s", "s"], ["j", "j"], ["j", "j"], ["s", "s"], ["e", "e"], ["e", "e"], ["w", "w"]]

>> "aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.)\3*)/)
=> [["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["a", "a"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["b", "b"], ["f", "f"], ["s", "s"], ["j", "j"], ["j", "j"], ["s", "s"], ["e", "e"], ["e", "e"], ["w", "w"]]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan):

> **str.scan(pattern) → array**
>   [...]
>   If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

This one:

```
"aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/(.)/)
```

has a group so you get an array of arrays: each individual result is a single element array.

The next one:

```
"aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.))/)
```

has two groups which happen to have the same value so you get two identical elements in your *individual result* arrays.

The third one:

```
"aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.)\2*)/)
```

again contains two groups but also contains a back-reference to the inner group so the outer group (AKA the first group) gobbles up duplicates and you get `["aaaaaa", "a"]`, `["jj", "j"]`, and `["ee", "e"]`.

The fourth one:

```
"aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.)\1*)/)
```

just tries to switch the back-reference to the outer group but `\1` isn't defined inside group 1 so it is equivalent to `/((.))/`.

The fifth one:

```
"aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/((.)\3*)/)
```

tries to refer to a non-existant group (group 3 when there are only two groups) so it behaves the same as `/((.))/`.

Comment: @stema: That's my favorite way to open an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`"aaaaaafbfbfsjjseew".scan(/(.)/)`  means the string can be splitted into individual array of strings.

Here parenthesis tells that it's an array, and the `.`-symbol in parenthesis represents number of characters in that individual string of array.

If we write for suppose `"hellovenkat".scan(/(...)/)` , this results
`[["hel"],["lov"],["enk"]]`. It doesn't give the last index, because it can not contain three characters.

If we give `"hello venkat".scan(/(...)/)`, this results as following.
Ans: `[["hel"], ["lo "], ["ven"], ["kat"]]`.